# How to configure nginx to host multiple sub-domains

Tags: nginx, dns, webserver, subdomain, nginx-config

I currently have example.com domain set up on NGINX and it works. I'd like to set up a subdomain test.example.com, but after following multiple different instructions I either keep getting 404 or being redirected to main domain.

My server configuration and file-structure look like this:

```
/usr/local/nginx
├── conf
│   ├── fastcgi_params
│   ├── includes
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   ├── nginx.conf.save
│   ├── sites
│   │   ├── example.com.conf
│   │   ├── test.example.com.conf
│   ├── uwsgi_params
│   └── win-utf
├── html
├── logs
└── snippets
    ├── ssl-example.com.conf
    └── ssl-params.conf

/var/www
├── example.com
│   └── ...
└── test.example.com
    └── index.html
```

I've updated DNS records so that  "*.example.com" points to the same IP

Default domain example.com.conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name exmaple.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/lets-encrypt/example.com;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        break;
    }
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/includes/m2-php71.conf;
}
```

And subdomain test.example.com.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;    
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.exampe.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/lets-encrypt/test.example.com;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        break;
    }
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/includes/m2-php71.conf;
}
```

when I remove listen 443 part, it redirects to the main domain.

I'd like the request for sub-domain test.example.com to be served from var/www/test.subdomain.com but cant seem to get past 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following -

1. remove `www.example.com` from one of the two configurations.
2. Add `alias` in server section for both the configs.

Comment: I don't undesrtand your suggestion: "example.com" is already on only one config file, not two as you implied in your answer.

Comment: I think user has updated the question. In this case you can just do point 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the php.conf file. I should have realized that as I was able to load index.html file but not the .php one. After including the right php.conf file it all started to work.